# How to authorize for Amazon's Alexa API?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I want to send a request to [this Amazon Alexa API](https://alexa.amazon.com/api/activities?startTime=&size=50&offset=-1).

That page contains the last 50 activities I made with my Amazon Echo. The page returns JSON. Before you can request that page, you need to authorize your account, so the proper cookies are set in your browser.

If I do something simple as:

```
const rp = require("request-promise");

const options = {
    method: "GET",
    uri: "https://alexa.amazon.com/api/activities?startTime=&size=50&offset=-1",
    json: true
};

rp(options).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

I can send a GET request to that URL. This works fine, except Amazon has no idea it's me who's sending the request, because I haven't authorized my NodeJS application.

I've successfully copied ~10 cookies from my regular browser into an incognito tab and authorized that way, so I know copying the cookies will work. After adding them all using `tough-cookie`, it didn't work, unfortunately. I still got redirected to the signin page (according to the error response).

How do I authorize for this API, so I can send my requests?

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for a solution for this too. The best idea I have is to use [account linking](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/link-an-alexa-user-with-a-user-in-your-system.html), but I haven't try it yet. Looks like [ASK-CLI](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/account-linking-operations.html) has interface for this also, but I can't figure it out how to use it (what is that URL?). For linking account to 3rd party server is not easy, but link it back to Amazon for the json API should not be that complicated.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Do you have any idea, how I might be able to do it, though? I have looked at account linking, but I just want my own account. This really doesn't have anything to do with Alexa, except she's the one who pushes requests to Amazon's API.

Comment: I am working on a skill, so account linking make sense for me, as for me to extract user info (i.e. json), I need the user gave me permission. Amazon keep the info very tight, and is very difficult to grab any info from them without authentication. The other way I was thinking is to use an automated login tool like Python's mechanize, but is a hack. I am going to try the account linking and see how it goes.

Comment: Just tried to access the json from the API via account linking to Amazon OA server -- even that doesn't work

Comment: Damn, I thought it didn't work. I've spoken with 4 Amazon people now (one being an "Alexa Developer Specialist" and all of them kept refering me to the developer forums... Great, I already asked on there :-( Oh well, thanks a lot for the help. It definitely saved me a lot of time :-)